# How to disable Navigation Keys in Bash Shell?

Tags: linux, bash, fedora, gnome-terminal, key-binding

I've did a serious research on <s>Google</s> Web and Stack Exchange websites prior asking the question, and come across to keywords and got acquainted with their meanings such as `bind`, `bind -r`, `read`, `/etc/inputrc`, `~/.inputrc` `\e`, `[A`, `[B`, `[C`, `[D`, and `GNU Readline` what I didn't know about before.

I tried to disable myself but could do that only to partial effect.

What I really want is to completely disable Text Navigational Keys alongside Page Navigational Keys in Bash, and possibly in all consoles.

I do it because I want to enforce the Vim key bindings *everywhere possible*, and had already set `set -o vim` to *benefit* from Vim modes presence in Bash.

I think the most correct way would be achieving so through `~\.inputrc`, tried, failed.

Comment: See this on [Stackexchange Unix](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/197015/remap-cursor-keys-in-bash-vi-mode-to-nop-disable-cursors).

Comment: Thanks, it really worked, it seems `:""` that part must follow the key codes inside the file to **un**map them. I could map `[H`, `[F`, `[5~`, `[6~` disabling the page navigation keys as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the link I provided worked, we can post it as an answer.

Adding the following to `.inputrc` will map the arrow keys to nothing.

```
$if mode=vi
"\eOD":""
"\e[D":""
"\eOC":""
"\e[C":""
"\eOA":""
"\e[A":""
"\eOB":""
"\e[B":""
$endif
```

Source: This [Stack Exchange Unix Post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/197015/remap-cursor-keys-in-bash-vi-mode-to-nop-disable-cursors).